# Column count error

Tags: php, mysql

I'm getting the following error: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1 from this query:

```
$movetohistory = mysql_query("INSERT INTO $storehistory SELECT * FROM $storetbl WHERE $time - datecreated >= 432000") or die ("Query failed: " . mysql_error() . " Actual query: " . $query);
```

I've echo'd out $storehistory, $storetbl, $time & all is fine. Both tables have identical columns / datatype. The only thing I could assume is that since $storetbl doesn't have All fields filled out, it's getting a column count error. HOWEVER, I thought specifying SELECT *ALL would over ride that.

If you could point me in the right direction, I'd appreciate that. And if you need more snippets, let me know.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your subquery is returning more columns than can be inserted:

```
INSERT INTO $storehistory SELECT * FROM $storetbl WHERE $time - datecreated >= 432000"
```

For clarity, you should parenthesize your subquery:

```
INSERT INTO $storehistory (SELECT * FROM $storetbl WHERE $time - datecreated >= 432000)"
```

EDIT:

I just executed this query, and it worked perfectly with two identical tables:

```
insert into users_copy select * from users
```

I would double-check that your data structures are identical.

Comment: You are indeed correct. I overlooked one slight data structure in a column. Thank you for your thoroughness. Solved!

Answer (score 0):

This kind of code is very hard to maintain in the face of database changes.

I suggest you explicitly list the column in both the INSERT and the SELECT portions.  It is possible, for instance, to change the column order of a table in production, or add or remove columns.